# I want to fix issue with @Before annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

**This is the @before annotation that I can't solve**

```
@Before
public void initDb() {
    {
        User newUser = new User("testUser@mail.com", "testUser", "****");
        userService.createUser(newUser);
    }
    {
        User newUser = new User("testAdmin@mail.com", "testUser", "****");
        userService.createUser(newUser);
    }
}
```

**Below are all my imports**

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import java.util.List;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import com.leadApp.Entities.Task;
import com.leadApp.Entities.User;
import com.leadApp.services.TaskService;
import com.leadApp.services.UserService;
```

**I would appreciate if someone can give an insight of what next I can do, I am using eclipse Oxygen**

Comment: Hint: You forgot to ask a question or state what your issue actually is.

Comment: I would suggest to remove the blocks within `initDb()`. It is unusual in Java to open blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using JUnit 5 AKA JUnit Jupiter.

The annotation is named `BeforeEach`, not `Before`. And of course, it should be imported from an `org.junit.jupiter` package, not from `org.aspectj.lang.annotation`, which has nothing to do with JUnit.

There is a guide, you should read it: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

Comment: Thank you for this, when I changed the annotation to @BeforeEach it was fixed...